# FilePond A11Y questions

Tags: filepond

I know that FilePond advertises itself as accessible, and I see some aria attributes on the underlying  that is created...but I can't see quite how to add any additional a11y-related props (e.g., aria-invalid), nor how to control what is added automatically (e.g., having aria-labelledby reference any label or error information that might be a part of my implementation of a file upload field).

I have tried passing additional props to the existing React adapter, as well as making a copy of the existing React adapter locally in my project and trying to set additional properties on the rendered input (which I assume means that somewhere in the bowels of the more generic FilePond project, it really just uses that input field as a reference, and then creates its own instead?).

I would love to learn that I am just missing something existing in the API - but alternately I have also [filed an issue on the project github](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/776) in case this is just an issue with the existing implementation (or possibly even morphs into a feature request).

Answer (score -1):

[From the project owner](https://github.com/pqina/filepond/issues/776):

"Hi, Yes all internals are managed by FilePond and there's currently no way to dynamically add custom attributes to internal fields (apart from id / class)."

Comment: Emphasis _currently_ see rest of reply → "On which internal elements would you like to add attributes? And are these attributes that should always be there or attributes to link FilePond to other elements around it?"

Comment: Yes, good clarification - just wanted to get the current answer here (with a link to the conversation about future changes) to help tie together the various corners of the internet...)